# Open PowerPoint and copy from Excel to specific slide

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am wanting to open an existing PowerPoint template and select slide 3 and copy a table from my spreadsheet to the PowerPoint slide.

Please can someone show me how to do this?

```
Sub Open_PowerPoint_Presentation()
'Opens a PowerPoint Document from Excel

    Dim objPPT As Object
    Dim PPSlide As Object

    Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set PPSlide = objPPT.Slides(5)

    objPPT.Visible = True

    'Change the directory path and file name to the location
     'of your document

    objPPT.Presentations.Open "\\MI-FILESERVE1\Shared Folders\Shared_Business_Dev\assets\Tender Time Allocation Deck.pptx"

    PPSlide.Select




     End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be CAREFUL : **You cannot paste in the Shapes of your Slide if the collection is empty**

I.E. : you'll need a slide with at least a title or a shape (square, triangle, ...) to be able to paste what you have copied in your clipboard.

**Here are the basics**, you should correct the excel lines to copy what you want :

```
Sub Open_PowerPoint_Presentation()

Dim objPPT As Object, _
    PPTPrez As PowerPoint.Presentation, _
    pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

Set PPTPrez = objPPT.Presentations.Open("\\MI-FILESERVE1\Shared Folders\Shared_Business_Dev\assets\Tender Time Allocation Deck.pptx")
Set pSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(5)

If pSlide.Shapes.Count <> 0 Then
    'Table
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Named Range").Copy
    pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    'OR
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Named Range").CopyPicture
    pSlide.Shapes.Paste

    'Charts
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graph1").ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    'OR
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graph1").ActiveChart.ChartArea.CopyPicture
    pSlide.Shapes.Paste
Else
    MsgBox "There is no shape in this Slide (" & pSlide.SlideIndex & ")." & vbCrLf & "Please use a slide with at least one shape, not a blank slide", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks I tried your code, however I get the following error: shapes (unknown member) invalid request. clipboard Is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here

Comment: thanks a lot, this seems to do the trick. I do appreciate your help and apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Don't worry everybody is getting started sometime. I'll explained the misunderstand in the duplicate to clear the air. Anyway glad I could help. Enjoy SO ;)